# Link multiple services to one domain

Tags: web, dns, web-hosting

How can I link and or map multiple web services to my domain?

I would like my website which has domain and hosting on g daddy to have one page from square-space and or wix

Essentially most of the webpages are on go-daddy but i want a few pages to be from from square-space/wix. so if i have a page under the uri /animals it would be loading a page from sq-space or wix.

I was going to create and Iframe but i do not think that is the best method for this. I do not think changing the name-servers will solve this issue as it will end up taking my site down completely and replacing it with wix.

Comment: if you want the "remote" pages to appear as part of your site, without mixing in "example.com" and "othersite.net"-type absolute addresses, your main site would have to proxy those files.

Comment: would that be in the dns settings on godaddy then? or how would i go about that.   essentially right now the wix page is something like xxxx.wix.com/my-page   and i want to add only the page to the site.